# getting the name of the interface "FloatingPoint" and not the class name being extended "DataTypeA"

Tags: java, oop, interface

I am new to java and I am having a small problem here, where following classes are as follows defined:

```
public interface FloatingPoint extends DataTypeA {
```

,

```
public interface DataTypeA extends _ElementA {
```

and

```
public interface _ElementA extends EObject {
```

when I use the following lines:

```
for (int i = 0, size = MetaObject.getEAllReferences().size(); i < size; ++i) 
{
    EReference Reference = MetaObject.getEAllReferences().get(i);

    if (Reference.isContainment()){

        if (Reference.getEType() instanceof EClass) {

             EClass ContainedClass = (EClass) Reference.getEType();
             String ClassName = ContainedClass.getName();
             System.out.println(ClassName);
```

I get "DataTypeA" but I want to have the name of the interface itself "FloatingPoint".

Does anyone has an idea how to solve such a problem!!

Comment: What's `EClass`, `Reference`, `ContainedClass`, `EObject`?

Comment: Did you try to call two times your `getEReferenceType()` ?

Comment: Also please describe what do you want to get. Like, "I want to get the name of the interface which ...".

Comment: EClass is for ECore language as am using emf. Reference is the containment reference of an object and am using to get the contained class name
    Reference.getEType().getName();

Comment: I think @lexicore want a bit more information than that.

Comment: @George I'm voting to close. Please read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please stick to the Java naming conventions about variable naming - most important thing: start variables with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase, and constants are in full uppercase. That immediately fixes the problems with the syntax coloring above, as StackOverflow depends on you following the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `java.lang.Class#getInterfaces`. As per java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()) :

> It determines the interfaces implemented by the class or interface
>   represented by this object. If this object represents a class, the
>   return value is an array containing objects representing all
>   interfaces implemented by the class. The order of the interface
>   objects in the array correspond to the order of the interface names
>   in the implements clause of the declaration of the class represented
>   by this object.

For example :

```
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
Class<?>[] interfaces = s.getClass().getInterfaces();
Arrays.stream(interfaces).map(e -> e.getName()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
java.util.List
java.util.RandomAccess
java.lang.Cloneable
java.io.Serializable
```

Here which class or interfaces `ArrayList` extends/implemented.

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Answer (score -3):

Inherited classes are called "super" in Java.

myClass.super will get the class you extend, so I believe you could go for ContainedClass.super.getName(); - but I have to little code to be sure ;)

Comment: `myClass.super` or `ContainedClass.super.getName()` is invalid java syntax